# How to make a second merge request to a forked repo while the first is still pending approval?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have forked a repo in Gitlab, fixed a syntax error (locally), commited it (let's say commit #1), pushed to the master branch and submitted a merge request.

Now let's say I want to make a second merge request with a different commit. I make the change, commit it (#2), open a merge request and... the previous commit (#1) is listed alongside the last one (#2) in the new MR. What I want is to just have commit #2 in the new MR.

What is the proper way of going about this? I assume my options are:
a) create a new feature branch from master (before #1 was created). But I couldn't find a way to do this with Gitlab.
b) revert #1 and then new feature branch, commit #2 and submit MR. The problem with this option is... wouldn't this affect the first MR? (pending approval still) Like if I delete my commit locally, wouldn't that affect MR #1? (at least in Github local changes in the branch used in a pull request, automatically change the PR itself)

Comment: I recommend reading https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html for GitLab's suggestions about how to use branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way is not to do all the work on the master branch in your fork but to use a separate branch for each merge request / each feature / bugfix / whatever you want to do.

When one updates the branch of a fork on GitLab, and there already is an ongoing merge request involving that branch, then all the updates to the branch will also land in the merge request.

So the workflow for working on seperate issues while merge requests are still being reviewed could be:

- fork the repo in GitLab
- create a new branch based on the master branch, let's call it `feature-one`, via `git checkout -b feature-one master`
- do the changes and commit them (say commit #1)
- create a merge request for branch `feature-one`

For the next merge request, just create another branch based on the master branch in your fork, say `feature-two`, via `git checkout -b feature-two master` and work on that for the next feature. Then you can create a new merge request for the second branch without affecting the changes from the first merge request.

So basically just create separate branches for separate merge requests.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Striezel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68231988/1202124) contains the correct/recommended workflow to use.

Now, in case anyone finds themselves in the same situation I did, here's how option a) is accomplished in Gitlab:

1.- Repository -> Commits. You'll see something like this:

[image]

The topmost is commit #1

2.- Copy the commit hash as marked in the pic above (of commit #0).

3.- Repository -> Files -> + -> New branch
[image]

4.- Click on the 'create form' field and paste the commit hash. Hit Enter. Create a branch.
[image]

Now you have a branch with the state before commit #1. Make commit #2 and then merge request from the bugfix/broken-link branch.

Again, stick to [Striezel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68231988/1202124) for general workflow, and this one for how to get out of the hole if you ever find yourself in this situation.